# refactoring jquery addClass removeClass

Tags: jquery, refactoring

I have the effect I want, but I know it could be coded more efficiently.

Here's the effect...

http://brinsterinc.com/fw/dcp/steps_vert.html

And here's the jQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $( "#1" ).addClass( "vstepCycle" ).delay(1000).queue(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("vstepCycle").dequeue();
            });
   }, 3000);
   setTimeout(function(){
        $( "#2" ).addClass( "vstepCycle" ).delay(1000).queue(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("vstepCycle").dequeue();
            });
   }, 4000);
   setTimeout(function(){
        $( "#3" ).addClass( "vstepCycle" ).delay(1000).queue(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("vstepCycle").dequeue();
            });
   }, 5000);
   setTimeout(function(){
        $( "#4" ).addClass( "vstepCycle" ).delay(1000).queue(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("vstepCycle").dequeue();
            });
   }, 6000);
});
```

Trying to learn so any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use Jquery UI, then it has [addClass](http://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/) and other functions which support `duration`, so that you can compress all your code into one or two lines such as :

`setTimeout(function(){ 
    $( "#1" ).addClass( "vstepCycle", 1000).removeClass("vstepCycle",1000) 
   }, 3000);`